# How to run IronPython as a script

Tags: ironpython

I would like to run ironpython as a script instead of compiling the ironpython code into an executable. is there a way to run ironpython as a script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the interpreter is installed in the IronPython sub-directory off of the Program Files folder.  The name is `ipy.exe`.  So, if your script is `myscript.py`:

```
  C:> c:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7.1\ipy.exe" myscript.py
```

Answer (score 0):

For avoiding the full path, Add IronPython folder path in you environment variable PATH.
 Then launch **cmd** and type

```
ipy
```

[image]